# Fill array in for-loop with sequences of different lengths

Tags: r, for-loop, indexing

I've got some struggle with a small issue. What I want to get is a *dim=1 array* to be filled up with help of this for-loop.

Minimal-Example (it's not working!):

```
Numbers <- seq(1,5)
Result  <- array(NA)

for(n in Numbers){
  Result[n] <- seq(n,5)  
  # The Result array should be like this:           
  # (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 3, 4, 5, 4, 5, 5)
}
```

I guess there a two problems:

- The `Result[n]` don't have the same length
- The index `n` in `Result[n]` is wrong. Actually, it should be dynamic, thus, change with every new `n`.

Can you guys help me?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can do this with `sapply`

```
unlist(sapply(Numbers, function(x) seq(x, 5)))
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 4 5 5
```

---

Or using the `for` loop

```
Result <- c()
for(n in Numbers){
 Result <- c(Result, seq(n, 5))
 }
Result
#[1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 4 5 5
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! :-)

Answer (score 1):

Using `sequence` and `rep`:

```
n <- 5
sequence(n:1) + rep(0:(n-1), n:1)
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 4 5 5
```

---

You may also create an 'oversized' matrix and select the lower triangle:

```
m <- matrix(c(NA, 1:n), nrow = n + 1, ncol = n + 1)
m[lower.tri(m)]
# [1] 1 2 3 4 5 2 3 4 5 3 4 5 4 5 5
```

Comment: thank you! Both answers are very nice! :-)